# Jacoco is analysing class twice and failing

Tags: scala, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I currently have this configuration for JaCoCo in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin> 
            <!-- Maven JaCoCo Plugin configuration for Code Coverage Report -->
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
```

When I run `mvn clean verify site`, I get a failed build, based in this warning (and important thing: I have only 1 class, `SayHello.scala`):

```
Analyzed bundle 'dummy-project' with 2 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for bundle dummy-project: classes missed count is 1, but expected maximum is 0
Failed to execute goal org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.5:check (default-check) on project dummy-project: Coverage checks have not been met. See log for details.
```

And finally, when I check the report, it's analysing the same class (the only difference is the extra "." in the second line), failing in one of them:

[image]

**Update**

*SayHello.scala*

```
package com.dummy

object SayHello {

def sayIt: String = "hello, world"

}
```

*SayHelloTest.scala*

```
package com.dummy

import org.scalatest.funsuite.AnyFunSuite
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class SayHelloTest extends AnyFunSuite with Matchers {

test("SayHello says hello") {
  SayHello.sayIt shouldBe "hello, world"

}
```

}

Anyone had a similar issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JaCoCo analyzes `.class` files, not source files. The Scala compiler may produce multiple `.class` files from a single source file. Your `SayHello.scala` class most likely contains a companion `object`. An `object` is always compiled to a class of the same name with `$` at the end, which implements the companion object singleton at the bytecode level. If you go to your `target/classes` directory, you'll most likely see those two files there - `SayHello.class` and `SayHello$.class`.

Two records in the JaCoCo report correspond to those two class files. The dot at the end instead of a `$` is most likely a jacoco report rendering issue.

To skip the companion object class from analyzing, just add it to your exclusion list:

```xml
<configuration>
  <excludes>
    <exclude>**/*Test.class</exclude>
    <exclude>**/*$.class</exclude>
  </excludes>
</configuration>
```

However, it seems that coverage of the methods in the companion object is attributed to `SayHello$.class`, not `SayHello.class`, so by removing the `$` class from the list, you essentially lose the coverage.

I'm not aware of any workarounds for the Maven+JaCoCo setup, apparently the `jacoco-maven-plugin` is not really Scala-aware. However, the sbt plugin appears to have worked around these issues, see e.g. https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/using-jacoco-a-code-coverage-tool-for-scala/

If switching to sbt is not an option, you could take a look at some Scala-specific code coverage tools, like [scoverage](http://scoverage.org/), which also has a [maven plugin](https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin).

Comment: Thank you, @Sergei, makes all the sense. After apply the change you suggested, this indeed reduced the analysed files. However, now it's saying that I don't have any test coverage (that "green" one, that had 100% coverage disappeared).  Any thoughts?

Comment: @JuliaBel the green one should have disappeared, as it's the one with dot at the end. The "regular" one (without the dot) should stay in the report. If you have a test that covers the `SayHello` class, then it should have coverage, but it's hard to say why it's red, without looking at its source and the source of its test. Could you add the sources to the question?

Comment: Sure, just included. Thank you.

Comment: I believe `jacoco-maven-plugin` is not really scala-aware, so my advice would be to either switch to sbt, or to pick another coverage tool. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information. Scoverage works as a charm